# How can I get all the attributes of a HTML tag?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I get all the attributes of a HTML tag?

```
listinp = soup('input')
for input in listinp:
    # get all attr on this tag in dict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pretiffy() in BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib2, BeautifulSoup
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
host = "http://google.com"
site = opener.open(host)
html = site.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.pretiffy()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `attrs`:

```
for tag in listinp:
    print dict(tag.attrs)
```